# Tower of Hanoi, graph requirements

Tags: towers-of-hanoi

Hi we are trying to find out what are the minimal requirements for a graph to be able to solve the hanoi problem.
Where the vertex are the pegs, and each edge represent a possible movement from one peg to another.
So basicly its Hanoi problem with restrictions that tell us what are our possible moves.
There can be any number of pegs and any number of discs.
So far we found that we need a strongly connected graph. but there is no explanation why.
If anyone can shed some light on the subject it will be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Have you read: [Tower of Hanoi - Graphical Representation (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi#Graphical_representation)? It   gives a recursive construction for building (more-or-less) the same graph you're looking for. You can combine this formula with proof by induction to show that the graph must be strongly connected, (or rather, to show that it is "connected", assuming we are using an *undirected* graph).

Comment: It's perfectly valid to use a undirected graph as each move you make is "undoable", right? If you move pegs from A to B, you can decide to undo that move by moving the same pegs back from B to A. So if there is an edge from A to B in your directed graph, by the same undo argument, there must be an edge to B to A. From this we see that using a directed graph is the same as using an undirected graph -- we can take edge pairs (A,B) and (B,A) in a directed graph and equivalently have an edge {A,B} in an undirected graph.

Comment: Thanks' iv'e read that part in wikipedia, but still didnt understand if
strongly connect is
a Necessity condition
or sufficiency condition
Thanks for the help!
@JamesLawson
and for your puropsal in the second comment. 
in our assignment its possible an edge A to B, but not B to A

Comment: G is a Tower of Hanoi graph => G is connected. The converse is not necessary true. In other words, connectivity is a necessary condition but not a sufficient condition. To prove this, you could find a graph that is connected but is not a Tower of Hanoi graph.

Comment: There are many graphs that don't represent the Tower of Hanoi - these graphs don't track of how many pegs, how many discs and the valid moves given the number of discs and pegs. For example, [this graph, G](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f4/Network_Community_Structure.svg) is connected, but there are no possible values of P and D such that G represents a valid Tower of Hanoi graph for any (P, D). Here integers P, D denote the number of pegs and discs respectively for an instance of the Tower of Hanoi problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help!:)